# Back button to previous partialview

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

In my .Net MVC4 project the view contains partialviews, the partialviews replaced on another after each corresponding `Ajax.Beginform` with option `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,`
So the senario is

1. Partialview1 renders on first `Ajax.Beginform` call
2. Submit form, partialview2 render on 2nd `Ajax.beginform`, so partialview1 is replaced by partialview2

3. **A previous button recalls partialview1**

Im wondering how to implement step3 that goes to previous partialview with something simple as history back.

Answer (score 0):

**First Way:** I think the best way to do that with browser Back button is to use `history.pushState`

How to implement it depends on your situation on `View`.

Some links about `pushState`:

http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

**Second Way:** If you don't want to use browsers Back buttom you can use js:

```
function getBack()
{
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '@Url.Action("ReturnPartialViewControllerMethod")',
     success: function(data) {
           // data is your view
          $('#divForParticialView').html(data);
     }
   });
}
```

and in your Html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getBack()">Get Back</a>
```

Comment: Ty for reply, Browser back button is not really what im searching for, need something does back on a part of the big html view

Comment: I think than you should use **js** and replace parts of **DOM** on `ajax` call.

Comment: I think I might got an idea by what ur saying, the `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` does clear content of a html tag and replace with new content, but if I create an empty reserved element and fill content in this instead, so the element that needs to be replaced can just use `.hide()`

Comment: yes, you right. As I say, it depends on your situation. I Updated answer with some example.